# How to get prototype properties

Tags: javascript, prototype

i write this code  but i don`t now why my console.log give me undefined and how can i get value of prototype properties or functions

```js
(function() {

    function Users() {}
    Users.prototype.getUser = function() {
      $.getJSON('/usersList/users.json', function(request) {
        Users.prototype.allUsers = request.users;
      });
    }

    var users = new Users();
    users.getUsers();

    console.log(users.allUsers);
  }
  ())
```

What i wont to achieve is to have this user list as my object property like User.allUsers in some array.
Thanks

Comment: `Quiz` != `Users`. Please fix that first.

Comment: Why would you want to make `allUsers` a prototype property? Is it really shared by all instances of the class? If yes, why is `getUsers` an instance method?

Comment: And finally, `getJSON` is **asynchronous**. [It won't set the property until later (or never in case of an error)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572), that's why it's still `undefined` when you access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous.

When you create an object from `User` prototype, `$.getJSON` has to call its callback yet.

In the other hand, you're trying to simulate global variables adding data properties to a given prototype. This is a bad practice and, at the end of the day, you've already realized that you got stuck on this approach.

What you need an initialization code executed whenever the site or app is started so those `allUsers` are called once and injected everywhere:

```
const initApp = () =>  Promise.all([
    $.getJSON("/someData/users.json")
    // other comma-separated async functions which return promises
])

initApp().then(([allUsers, otherData, yetAnotherData]) => {

    callSomeFunctionWhichRequiresAllUsers(allUsers)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but is there any simple solution for this. I just want to use this json data in all my functions

Comment: @JelenaK No problem. Sorry, there's no other way. Well, there're variants of the same approach, but at the end of the day, asynchronous code implies working with callbacks or promises.

Comment: sorry for bothering you but what is callback approach